# Alternate for "drop" in context of "A taxi will drop you to that place"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a decent alternative for the word "drop" in context of helping someone by giving them a lift to a place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other ways to express this:

**A taxi will take you to that place.**

**A taxi will drop you off at that place.**

**A taxi will let you off at that place.**

**A taxi can bring you to that place.**

Comment: Please explain why someone would choose each of these.